# Displaying HTML if data is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
    <h1>{{title | uppercase}}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li v-repeat="todos" v-on="click: done = !done" class="{{done ? 'done' : ''}}">
            {{content}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        title: 'todos',
        todos: [] //testing with data use: [{done:false,content:'testing'}]
    }
});
```

Or: http://jsfiddle.net/ksumarine/yMv7y/301/

I would like to display "No todos at this time" or something similar if the data comes back as empty. I can't figure out how to do this.

Also, when I have something similar to this in my app, I see the mustache bindings on the page before Vue replaces it with the data. Any thoughts on how to hide the bindings from the user?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `v-if="!todos.length"` to make the message display only when the todos array is empty.

For the flash of bindings, use `v-cloak` together with a CSS rule to hide it until the compilation finishes.

Combined example: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/304/